# Templatized [] or () operator overload - possible without using type as arg?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

In the same way as you can do this...

```
template< typename T >
T GetValue( const int index ) const;

char c = GetValue< char >( 0 );
```

...is it possible to do this:

```
template< typename T >
T operator[]( const char* key ) const;

char c = GetValue< char >( "some key" );    // *** This doesn't compile ***
```

...or this:

```
template< typename T >
T Foo::operator()( const char* key ) const;

char c = Foo< char >( "some key" );    // *** This doesn't compile ***
```

The two examples above don't compile due to the **< char >** and without it I get the "can't deduce type" error (I understand why that is the case).

The closest I can get is specify a 'default value' which gets rid of the "can't deduce type" error, so something like this:

```
template< typename T >
T operator()( const char* key, const T& defaultValue ) const;

char c = Foo( "some key", 'x' );
```

But, that isn't really what I want.

**EDIT**

Essentially, this is what I'm doing:

```
class Collection
{
  ...

  template< typename T >
  T operator[]( const char* key ) const;

  template< typename T >
  void Add( const char* key, const T& value );

  ...
}
```

And this is how I'd like to use it:

```
Collection col;
col.Add( "some key", 123 );
col.Add( "another key", 'x' );
col.Add( "and another", 1.23 );

char c = col< char >[ "another key" ];
```

Comment: Well if you understand the error, how would you expect it to be able to deduce the type? Do you mean you want the return type of the operator to be (dependant on) the template argument of the class which has the operator?

Comment: Ah. Thanks @BoBTFish that prodded my thinking... I'd somehow managed to ignore that the operator is closely tied to the class. Still, is there no way to explicitly specify the type (like in the first code block)?

Comment: So you have, say, `MyVector<std::string>`, you want `MyVector::operator[]` to automatically return `string&` (even though it is indexed on some irrelevant integer type)?

Comment: I'm hoping i can tell it the type `string s = someVector< string >[ 0 ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to achieve something like this:

```
struct S {
   template< typename T >
   T operator[]( const char* key ) const {
       return key[0];
   }
   template< typename T >
   T operator()( const char *key) const {
       return key[0];
   }
};

int main() {
   S s;
   char c = s.operator[]<char>("some key");
   c = s.operator()<char>("some key");
   (void)c;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CIHpT18Hypp2EmAV)

---

If that syntax doesn't fit your application you could try to use tag dispatching:

```
struct S {
   template< typename T >
   T operator()(const char *key, T) const {
       return key[0];
   }
};

int main() {
   S s;
   char c = s("some key", char{});
   (void)c;
}
```

[[live demo]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Ll2EKqM9En0hB7i2)

This however can be harder to apply to `operator[]` as it can only take one argument.

Comment: Fantastic, you've just preempted my request for a more accessible syntax - any chance that can be further 'refined' into a more 'standard' syntax?

Comment: @grae22 unfortunetly use of `s<type>[param];` may cause some ambiguities in the language syntax... I'm afraid the change isn't considered at the moment...